# MYSQL LEFT JOIN Multiple Tables Twice

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have following MySQL Code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM b_movies, b_mov_rol_celeb, b_starcast 
LEFT JOIN bb_celebs ON b_mov_rol_celeb.celeb_id = bb_celebs.celeb_id 
  OR b_starcast.celeb_id = bb_celebs.celeb_id 
LEFT JOIN bb_roles ON b_mov_rol_celeb.role_id = bb_roles.role_id 
WHERE b_movies.id = '14';
```

Its giving error:

> Unknown column 'b_mov_rol_celeb.celeb_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Are you sure you haven't mistyped anything? Run this query: `SELECT celeb_id FROM b_mov_rol_celeb LIMIT 5` does it work as expected?

Comment: I can't test it right now, but have you tried adding brackets around this `b_mov_rol_celeb.celeb_id = bb_celebs.celeb_id OR b_starcast.celeb_id = bb_celebs.celeb_id` part?

Comment: @andyb:yep! h=i have tried. same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT m.title_slug, m.title, m.release_date,
       c.celeb_slug, c.celeb_name, 
       r.role_name,
       s.char_name
FROM b_movies m
INNER JOIN b_starcast s ON m.id = s.movie_id
INNER JOIN b_mov_rol_celeb mrc ON m.id = mrc.movie_id
LEFT JOIN bb_celebs c ON mrc.celeb_id = c.celeb_id OR s.celeb_id = c.celeb_id 
LEFT JOIN bb_roles r ON mrc.role_id = r.role_id 
WHERE m.id = '14';
```

The order of the tables matters in a left or right join.

Comment: I ran the query. I get this error: Unknown column 'b_starcast.celeb_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: @Kenh: Is there a relationship between the table `b_movies`, `b_starcast`, and `b_mov_rol_celeb`? You should change the query to use `LEFT JOIN`s, otherwise I don't see a solution.

Comment: yes b_movies.movie_id and b_starcast.movie_id, b_mov_rol_celeb.movie_id are same. bb_celebs contains celeb_id and celeb_name. i want celebnames from bb_celebs table for both b_mov_rol_celeb.celeb_id and b_starcasr.celeb_id

Comment: its not b_movies.movie_id its b_movies.id

Comment: @Kenh: I updated the query to select only `celebname` from the table `bb_celebs`. Try that and let me know if it goes through.

Comment: I have tables `b_movies` (contains basic movie info - i want all fields from this table), `bb_celebs` (contains celeb_name and celeb_id), `bb_roles` (contains role_name and role_id), `b_starcast` (contains celeb_id and charachter_name), `b_mov_rol_celeb` (contains movie_id role_id and celeb_id)

Comment: I ran the query and found duplicate entries. I want all the fields from all tables. I want info to be sorted by role_id like Directors: Celebname1, celebname2 same way for all the other roles alongwith starcast displayed as: celeb_name as char_name

Comment: Please help me with the query to display results as in above comments and how to eliminate duplicate info. I mean multiple rows have same info in some columns.

Comment: @Keneh: Without a full table schema, I can'c come up with a clear solution. Share the table schema. Share sample data. And present a resultset to show us how you want it to look when it is returned.

Comment: I have added sample data, schema. Please help!

Comment: @Kenh: The schemas and sample data looks good. However, forget about the way you want it to display on site. Show us a sample table what you want the query to return.

Comment: I have added Sample Data. In case of real Sample i want it like: [link](http://www.bollywoodhungama.com/movies/cast/14060/index.html)

Comment: @Kenh: Hmm... that doesn't tell much(everything) about what you want returned when you run the query. Please create a table, including all the details you want on the table when you would run a sample query searching for a specific ID or whatever you want to search in it for.

Comment: I have added the result and the way how it has to be displayed on site. Thanks.

Comment: @Kenh: I updated the query, try that. If it doesn't produce the kind of result you are looking for, please share what is the result it produces.

Comment: I have added the result. How do i parse/fetch the results to display on site as shown above?

Comment: @Kenh: If you have the desired result, then this question has been resolved. Accept the answer by clicking on the tick icon below the vote count on the left side of the answer. Then, write a new question so we can solve that in PHP. Make sure to provide the returned data, the output format, a reference to this question, and your PHP attempt at it, so me, and others, can help you with outputting it the way you want it to be outputted. Let me know here once you have posted the new question, so I can help.

Comment: Thanks. Please help me here: [Fetching Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059496/parse-fetch-mysql-query-result-to-display-in-specific-format)